# binascii.hexlify(b'variable') is this possible

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am trying to us binascii.hexlify(b'x') in a script where x is a variable in a for loop.  Currently each time I run my script it is using the character x and not what the variable x is storing.

I am using Python 3.7 32 bit.

Comment: `binascii.hexlify(x)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you tried `binascii.hexlify(x)` and it didn't work, so you tried putting `b` in front of it to convert it to bytes. That only works for string literals, not variables. For that you need `encode`:

```
binascii.hexlify(x.encode('utf-8'))
```

I don't know what encoding parameter you need to pass to `encode`, that depends on what you're doing with the resulting string. But `utf-8` is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You just want simply:

```
binascii.hexlify(x)
```